# How can I find IAC's which are using specif AWS managed Polcies

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-iam

As AWS managed AWSconfigRole Policy is deprecated, I wanted to find where is it in use before taking decommissioning action. Could you please guide me steps which important places I should be looking for?

I am aware about Access advisor tab to find the linked resources, any other function apart from that.

Thank you

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use `aws iam list-entities-for-policy --policy-arn <arn-of-policy>`

For exaple:

1. Open CloudShell or your configured `aws` CLI
2. `aws $ aws iam list-entities-for-policy --policy-arn arn:aws:iam::123456789:policy/service-role/AwsCodePipelineServiceRole-central-1-foo`